# Is there a way to ‘join’ (block) in POSIX threads, without exiting the joinee?

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, pthreads, blocking

I’m buried in multithreading / parallelism documents, trying to figure out how to implement a threading implementation in a programming language I’ve been designing.

I’m trying to map a mental model to the `pthreads.h` library, but I’m having trouble with one thing: I need my interpreter instances to continue to exist after they complete interpretation of a `routine` (the language’s closure/function data type), because I want to later assign *other* `routine`s to them for interpretation, thus saving me the thread and interpreter setup/teardown time.

This would be fine, except that `pthread_join(3)` requires that I call `pthread_exit(3)` to ‘unblock’ the original thread. How can I block the original thread (when it needs the result of executing the `routine`), and then unblock it when interpretation of the child routine is complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `pthread_cond_t`; wait on it on one thread and signal or broadcast it in the other.

Comment: Just a semaphore might be sufficient in this case - init with value 0, wait on it in one thread and post it in the other. Same principle, though.

Comment: When you say ‘wait on it,’ do you mean simply a tight loop against it in the original thread? That’s … well, I was trying to avoid such a hacky/lame solution. I want to actually freeze the thread using the `pthread.h` library if I can, so that it doesn’t even get scheduled: that should save a ton of execution time, no?

Comment: @elliotcable: I was referring to pthread_cond_wait: http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html

Comment: @Steve Jessop: semaphores would likely work just as well and are simpler, but aren't technically part of pthreads though :)

Comment: Yeah, are they "not part of pthreads" in a troublesome way, or just in the sense that they're in a different header? Is it legal for a POSIX implementation to provide pthreads, but not provide semaphores?

Comment: @Steve Jessop: I can't imagine any POSIX implementation that would provide pthreads and not semaphores. Consider my earlier reply overly pedantic :)

Comment: You might also consider using barriers.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you actually want an implementation of the [Thread Pool Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern). It makes for a fairly simple conceptual model, without repeated thread creation & tear down costs. Some OS's directly support it, on others it should be reasonably simple to implement using a queue and a semaphore.

Comment: Yes, pretty much. I’m just looking for the proper `pthread.h` calls, or whatever else I need to investigate, to create this.